# R.Java is ALWAYS disappearing?

Tags: android, r.java-file

No matter what app i build it seems like the `R.Java` file always disappears no matter what!

It is fine up in till i clean the project. From there it disappears.

I have "Build Automatically" enabled as well

Does any one know how to fix this. It is starting to get **very** annoying!

Comment: It disappears because it's a generated file, which is cleaned up when you say "Clean". It should reappear, though. Anything on the console?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Android plug-in won´t generate **R.java** file if you have any errors in **/res** folder.

Check if there is under **/res** directory. A lot times I used to fix it by this way.

Answer (score 1):

Works as designed, as it is a generated file.